# Length of a growing sequence C++

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, sequence

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 20;

int main()
{
    int n, a[MAX_SIZE]; // initialize array and its size
    cin >> n;                       //
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     //  ===> array input
        cin >> a[i];                //
    int max = 0;    // initializing a variable indicating the length of the longest sequence
    int i;
    int current = 0;    // makes sure the each loop begins from where the last has concluded 
    do
    {
        int count = 0; // counter indicating the length of the sequence.. resets after each loop
        for (i = current; a[i] <= a[i + 1] && i < n - 1; i++) // loops until a lower than the previous number is found or the array ends
        {
            count++;
        }
        current = i;    // makes so that the next loop can start from where the last has concluded
        if (count > max) max = count;   // determines the longest "growing" sequence of numbers
    } while (i < n);    // when all of the array elements are checked the program is done
    cout << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My commenting skills suck so don't be too hard on me. I've tried to explain as clearly as possible what I want to accomplish with my code as of misunderstandings in my previous questions.

TL;DR: To sum it up, this is (or at least should be) a program which finds the longest sequence length of "growing" numbers in an array. What does "growing" mean? A sequence in which every next number is either even or higher than the previous one. For example in `1 2 3 3 1 2` the "growing" sequence is `1 2 3 3` and its length (what should the output be) is 4. However, for some unknown reason, when I compile and input the array the program freezes without giving any output.. ever. Any ideas what could possibly cause that? Thanks for the help in advance !

Comment: Step through the program in a debugger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Oh I'm really sorry then. Thank you but what should I do with my question? Delete it or something? I don't want a huge wave of downvotes just because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `current = i;` is wrong.You should start from the element **after** the one you finished on. There's one more, but it will be easier to find once you fix this one. Both errors can be fixed by adding `+1` in propper places.

Note that you really **should** use a debugger, like the other people hinted. It would probably solve your problem in a minute. Please do that next time! :)

Comment: God, you're a life saver! Thanks a lot. I'm really sorry for troubling you with such a concern but I'm really all too new to programming and found way too much trouble trying to use the debugger.

Comment: One thing also mentioned in the comments above is, if you don't feel like using a debugger (which can definitely be confusing when you first start programming!), try just putting a ton of `cout`s in your code, and outputting the values of different variables at different points. Then, make sure they match what you expect them to be. That's basically what a debugger does for you anyways, just prettier ^^